# Avoid MachinePrecision numbers in Message

Tags: machine-precision, message-coding

Can I change the output of `Message` to not show `MachinePrecision` numbers?  E.g.

```
Bleh::test = "test `1`";
```

This is tolerable:

```
Message[Bleh::test, 0.01]
(* Bleh::test -- test 0.01` *)
```

This is not:

```
xx = 0.01;
Do[xx += 0.04, {5}]
Message[Bleh::test, xx]
(* Bleh::test -- test 0.21000000000000002` *)
```

Is there a way for `Message` to display this rounded off as:

```
xx
(* 0.21 *)
```

Comment: `Message[Bleh::test, ToString@xx]` uses the current `PrintPrecision`, I think. -- Well, no, apparently not, but it rounds the output as desired.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I thought it might be simple.  Want to add as an answer?

Comment: I think NumberForm or StandardForm will work better than ToString.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ToString` seems to round the output as is usually done in output cells (technically in `OutputForm`, which is not the same as the `"Output"` style):

```
xx = 0.01;
Do[xx += 0.04, {5}]
Message[Bleh::test, ToString@xx]
```

> Bleh::test: test 0.21

Comment: Single argument ToString uses OutputForm. If the number is a rational or needs scientific notation, the output will be very bad, e.g., `xx=1/7; Do[xx += 1/16, {5}]; Message[Bleh::test, ToString@xx]`

Comment: @CarlWoll Quite.  I took `MachinePrecision` to mean, well, `MachinePrecision`.

Comment: A rational example was simpler, but a scientific notation example is `xx = 1.1*^6; Do[xx += 1.1*^7, {5}]; Message[Bleh::test, ToString@xx]`. Basically, you should almost never use single argument ToString.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks, I didn't think of that.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, although @CarlWoll's suggestions of `StandardForm` or `NumberForm` might be more robust to non-MachinePrecision numbers.